How do I add custom field in swagger ui in django application?
With every request the api endpoint requires a header name 'VENDOR'. I need to create a field in Django swagger ui to add the VENDOR value and attach it to the headers in every request.
I tried customizing swagger settings in Django settings but it didnot work
I want something similar like the one in the image but has to be vendor in the field and add to its the request
image link

How exactly are you integrating Swagger into Django in the first place?

i have used drf-spectacular

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Extend swagger-ui.html by creating a file inside templates/spectacular/swagger-ui.html
here i have added a field called vendor and added to the headers in every requests.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
  <head>
    <title>API Documentation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ swagger_ui_css }}" />
    <style>
      html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }

      *,
      *:after,
      *:before {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      body {
        background: #fafafa;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      .vendor-input {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: none;
      }

      .swagger-ui .topbar {
        display: none;
        /* Hide the default top bar */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    <!-- Vendor input field placed after the API title and description -->
    <div class="vendor-input">
      <label for="vendor">Vendor:</label>
      <input type="text" id="vendor" name="vendor" />
    </div>
    <script src="{{ swagger_ui_bundle }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ swagger_ui_standalone }}"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        const vendorInputDiv = document.querySelector('.vendor-input');
        const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
          url: "/api/schema/",
          dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
          presets: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
            SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
          ],
          layout: "StandaloneLayout",
          onComplete: function() {
            // Move the vendor input field after the API title and description
            const info = document.querySelector('.swagger-ui .info');
            if (info) {
              info.appendChild(vendorInputDiv);
              vendorInputDiv.style.display = 'block';
            }
          },
          requestInterceptor: function(request) {
            const vendor = document.getElementById('vendor').value || 'test.com';
            if (vendor) {
              request.headers['VENDOR-SITE'] = vendor;
              request.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = "{{csrf_token }}"
            }
            return request;
          }
        });
        window.ui = ui;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
